# Any suggestion on how to simplify this code?

Tags: php

Example 1:

```
    $name                =$this->input->post('name', TRUE); 
    $address             =$this->input->post('address', TRUE);
    $website             =$this->input->post('website', TRUE);
    $phone               =$this->input->post('phone', TRUE);
    $fax                 =$this->input->post('fax', TRUE);
```

It make me some many code, because I allow user to input many information....

Comment: This is simple code, what so simplify more?

Comment: I think he wants some way of doing this in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
$fields = array('name', 'address', 'website', 'phone', 'fax');

foreach($fields as $field) {
    ${$field} = $this->input->post($field, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Noooo variable variables, arggh

Comment: But if the OP use the variable such as `$name` later, the variable is necessary.

Comment: yeah, but it's better to use an array for this. Never mind though, it'll work either way

Comment: Yes, variable variables are easy to have bug. If the OP don't mind change the other code, I agree to use an array:)

Answer (score 2):

You can build an array and walk through it.

```
$fields = array(); // Use an array rather than single variables
$my_fields = array("name", "address", "website"); // etc. etc.

foreach ($my_fields as $field)
 $fields[$field] = $this->input->post($field, TRUE);

print_r($fields); // A nice array with all the field values
```

Answer (score 1):

well the better way would be grouping the variables in an array:

```
$keys = array ('name', 'address', 'website', 'phone', 'fax');
$data = array();
foreach($keys as $k){
    $data[$k] = $this->input->post($k, TRUE);
}
```

you can always extract $data if you like, but i prefer keeping it in the array

you should put it in a function:

```
function fromRequest($method='post', $keys) {
    if ($method != 'post' && $method!= 'get') { throw new Exception('Invalid method'); }
    $data = array();
    foreach($keys as $k)
        $data[$k] = $this->input->$method($k, TRUE);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `eval`. Even if you want to use dynamic variables.

Comment: I'll +1 your `$data` solution (which is perfect) if you remove the second option with the variable variables :)

Comment: i like using eval, not for these kind of things, but as long as you are careful of what you're putting inside, it's very useful. I use it to generate code for some defined patterns

Comment: @galchen is the `$$k` the same as `${$k}`?